# Why $E/AutE$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{P}^1$?

Tags: elliptic-curves, group-isomorphism, complex-multiplication

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve which has complex multiplication over number field $K$.

Why $E/AutE$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb{P}^1$ ?

I tried to use first isomorphism theorem.
Let $E→\Bbb{P}^1$ be $(x,y)→x$, but I cannot find it's kernel.

Comment: The first isomorphism theorem is normally only stated for group homomorphisms.  But $\mathbb P^1$ isn't a group, nor is $\mathrm{Aut} E$ a subgroup of $E$.

Comment: Do you know the Riemann-Hurwitz Theorem? You can apply it to the quotient map $E \to E/\operatorname{Aut}(E)$ to show that the quotient has genus $< 1$.

Comment: No need that $E$ has CM. the subfield of $\Bbb{C}(x)[y]/(y^2-x^3-ax-b)$ fixed by $(x,y)\to (x,-y)$ is $\Bbb{C}(x)$. It remains to investigate the case where $Aut E$ is larger than $\pm 1$.